# Where are Odoo Attachment Files is Stored in Odoo 14

Tags: database, odoo, odoo-14

I'm planning doing some migration and I need to know where all the attachment files is stored. In [this forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/where-are-document-attachments-stored-529), there are some answers, but the binary value for column `ir_attachment.db_datas` is set to null for every record.

Comment: From which version do you migrate to 14?

Comment: Actually I want to migrate from Odoo 12 to Odoo 14, but I want to try to migrate from Odoo 14 to Odoo 14 in the different server first for exercise, because I don't want to mess with production server that currently running Odoo 12.

Comment: Then there shouldn't be any attachments saved directly in the database. That was something used in older versions, but IIRC since Odoo 8 attachments are saved in the filestore directory as default.

Comment: Ok, but where is the filstore located in my server? there is no setting for that location in my `odoo.conf`

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/misc/other/cmdline.html?highlight=filestore#cmdoption-odoo-bin-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As alredy mentioned in the comment section, the default location if not defined otherwise in `odoo.conf` file `data_dir` directory or Odoo service command `--data-dir` option, is `~/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/ODOO_DB_NAME` or `/var/lib/Odoo/filestore/ODOO_DB_NAME`. If defined otherwise using any of the options, you will find the filestore directory at that defined location.